# Nebula Grid - Select individual cells (CellSelectionEnabled)

Tags: java, swt, nebula

I am using Eclipse.org's Nebula Grid and want to access an individual cell. Not an individual GridItem, which can be accomplished by grid.select(...) but a cell. So lets say i have a grid like this:

```
final Grid grid = new Grid(shell,SWT.BORDER | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.H_SCROLL);
grid.setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
grid.setHeaderVisible(true);

GridColumn column = new GridColumn(grid, SWT.None);
column.setWidth(80);
GridColumn column2 = new GridColumn(grid, SWT.None);
column2.setWidth(80);
for(int i = 0; i<50; i++)
{
    GridItem item = new GridItem(grid, SWT.None);
    item.setText("Item" + i);
}
```

Like i said, grid.select selects the whole row, which is not what i want. I also tried grid.selectCell(...), but for some reason that wont work either. The coordinates used are with a high likeliness correct:

```
Button btn = new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH);
btn.setText("test");
btn.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter(){
public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e){
    Point pt = new Point(400,300);
    grid.selectCell(pt);
    }
});
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a Grid, the Point co-ordinates represent the intersecting column and the row item. i.e, x co-ordinate represents the index of the column and y co-ord is the row item index.

```
Button btn = new Button (shell, SWT.PUSH);
btn.setText ("test");
btn.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {

       // Here the x co-ordinate of the Point represents the column
       // index and y co-ordinate stands for the row index.
       // i.e, x = indexOf(focusColumn); and y = indexOf(focusItem);
       Point focusCell = grid.getFocusCell();
       grid.selectCell(focusCell);

        // eg., selects the intersecting cell of the first column(index = 0)
        // in the second row item(rowindex = 1).
        Point pt = new Point(0, 1);
        grid.selectCell(pt);
}
});
```